# SignalR shutdown stalls for about 25 sec with opened connections (it was a bug)

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I have a server running some controllers and one SignalR-hub. When running the server and closing it gracefully, it stops immediately, unless I have established a connection to my hub. In that case the shutdown process hangs for about 25 seconds before continuing. It first takes about 5 sec to reach `IHostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping` and then another 20 sec before exit. This only happens if I have refreshed my js-client and created a connection, so my guess is that some code somewhere tries to ask the client for a graceful exit and then times out? Only a guess though. Any other ideas? The hub is empty and do nothing. When pausing debug I only get `external code` I cannot step into. I'm using .NET 8 and the built-in SignalR.

If I do this I can halve the second part of the wait to 10 sec:

```
  services.AddSignalR(c =>
  {
    c.HandshakeTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    c.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
  });
```

If I comment out any of them I'm back at 20 sec. Only when both are set I get down to 10 sec.

Also, just noticed it only happens with WebSockets and not Long Polling or SSE.

Comment: It's a bug, fixed in 8.0.3 (which isn't released yet)

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed that (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/53165)